# In ng-options, is it possible to do preselection using the "(index, item) in vm.items" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When working with select in angularjs, I want to preselect a random index value for the select.

### ng-options

I have tried to use **ng-init** or setting it in the controller but it doesn't seem compatible with the way ng-options work.

```
<select
    ng-init = "vm.index = 1"
    ng-model = "vm.index"
    ng-options= "index as item.name for (index, item) in vm.items">
</select>`
```

```js
angular.module('app', [

  ])
  .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);

function appCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  //vm.selected = 3;
  vm.items = [{
    id: 1000,
    name: "item1",
    someArray: [{
      id: 0,
      name: "item1 - subItem1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "item1 - subItem2"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "item1 - subItem3"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "item1 - subItem4"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "item1 - subItem5"
    }]

  }, {
    id: 1001,
    name: "item2",
    someArray: [{
      id: 0,
      name: "item2 - subItem1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "item2 - subItem2"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "item2 - subItem3"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "item2 - subItem4"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "item2 - subItem5"
    }]
  }, {
    id: 1002,
    name: "item3",
    someArray: [{
      id: 0,
      name: "item3 - subItem1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "item3 - subItem2"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "item3 - subItem3"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "item3 - subItem4"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "item3 - subItem5"
    }]
  }];
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%
}

.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as vm">
  <div class="div1">

    <select ng-init="vm.selected = 1" ng-model="vm.selected" ng-options="index as item.name for (index, item) in vm.items track by item.id">
    </select>
    <h4>Index</h4>
    <pre ng-bind="vm.selected"></pre>
    <h4>Object</h4>
    <pre> {{ vm.items[vm.selected] | json }}</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <h3>subItems of index {{ vm.selected }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="subItem in vm.items[vm.selected].someArray track by subItem.id">
        {{ subItem.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Update

Thanks for the solutions. I have some extra context to add to this question.

My actual use case is an array of objects that each has an array property. The selected object will have its array property ng-repeated.

I want to see if there's any working solution to get the index of the array and then use the selected index instead of the actual object for the next ng-repeat.
This is all an effort to make my app more performant.

If you can convince me that using ng-model to get the selected object will not suffer performance penalties that amount to anything on a mobile device then I will gladly accept that answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the object repeat syntax when you actually have an array. Change it to use array syntax!

```
<select
    ng-init = "vm.selectedItem = vm.items[1]"
    ng-model = "vm.selectedItem"
    ng-options= "item as item.name for item in vm.items">
</select>
```

And then set the model to the item you want:

```
var randomIndex = 2;
vm.selectedItem = vm.items[randomIndex];
```

`$index` is also non-existent when using `ngOptions`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Technically, you're correct. I was using ng-repeat the same way as your provided solution previously. the problem is my actual array contains objects that has arrays in them and I have to use another ng-repeat on the array property of the selected object. I will update the question.

 I'm aware that I can't use $index with ng-options and that I'm using a hack --  an object syntax over an array. My intention was to get the vm.selected to be the index of the array so that my app can be more performant for my purposes.

Comment: I have changed my mind. There's no reason to work against angularjs. Perhaps the trick I learned with the object syntax over an array was a problematic approach.

Answer (score 0):

To select a specific option in your select HTML tag, you have to assign a whole object to ng-model instead of only an index.

HTML example (it will select first item from the array):

```
ng-init = "vm.selected = vm.items[0]"
```

controller example (it will select the last item from the array):

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);
function appCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items= [{
        id: 1000,
        name: "item1"
    }, {
        id: 1001,
        name: "item2"  
    }, {
        id:1002,
        name: "item3"
    }];
    vm.selected = vm.items[vm.items.length - 1];
}
```